# Using getElementsByName without starting at document root

Tags: javascript, dom

Is there a way to use `getElementsByName` without starting from the DOM root.

For example I have a div element, and want to start searching from that element.

If not, then do I have to write my own function that recursively iterates through the child nodes, or is there a different way to do it.

Comment: Have you considered using [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/) or [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)? It's  snap with one of those.

Comment: Do you really mean `getElementsByTagName` ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getElementsByName` and `getElementById` are both members of the `document` object, and aren't part of the `HTMLElement` prototype.  In modern browsers (IE8, Firefox, Chrome, Opera), you can use [`element.querySelectorAll("*[name='myName']")`](http://mdn.beonex.com/En/DOM/Element.querySelectorAll).

Other than that your alternative is to use a library like [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) or a framework such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com) (which uses Sizzle) to handle selectors.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really make any sense, because the value of each "id" attribute in every tag in the document must be unique.

Because of that, it doesn't matter where you "start".

**edit — never mind, if you're talking about `getElementsByTagName`**

Comment: He's talking about `getElementsByName` not `getElementsById`

Comment: Ah.  Well ok then!  Carry on.

Answer (score 0):

Basically its is DOM, so every time you search for some element by NAME or ID, it can be started from some reference point.

Say you want some element from Form named as `Form1`, then you can write

```
document.Form1.fieldName
```

which will give you particular field.

But it all should be absolute path. Because if you do have some reference, you can refer to its children.

Jquery anf yUI provides better support for fetching and setting of DOM elements. JQuery eases the things which are hard in javascript.

try [www.jquery.com](http://www.jquery.com)

thanks.

Comment: I think the whole point is that you can only start from the root by using document.getElementsByTagName. You can't replace document with a node somewhere in the middle of the DOM.

Answer (score -1):

have you tried.

document.getElementsbyTagName("div")[0].getElementsbyName("your search");

also with jQuery selectors the search for dom elements become quite easier.